# Error preparing queries for accessor in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, accessor, datastax-java-driver, lagom

In lagom project, I'm trying to use **[Accessors](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/object_mapper/using/)**
But I get an error.

> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error preparing queries for accessor TestAccessor
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:991)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2124)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:110)
>       at org.test.impl.persist.CassandraRepository.getAll(CassandraRepository.java:98)
>       at org.test.impl.workers.Worker.lambda$testMessage$2(Worker.java:91)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
>       at com.spotify.futures.ListenableToCompletableFutureWrapper.onSuccess(ListenableToCompletableFutureWrapper.java:49)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1237)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:911)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:822)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:664)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture.setResult(AbstractTransformFuture.java:245)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:177)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:911)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:822)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:664)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:174)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:198)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2600(RequestHandler.java:50)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:852)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:556)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1087)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1010)
>       at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>       at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>       at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.InboundTrafficMeter.channelRead(InboundTrafficMeter.java:38)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:647)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:582)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:499)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:461)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error preparing queries for accessor TestAccessor
>       at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AccessorMapper.prepare(AccessorMapper.java:61)
>       at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.getAccessor(MappingManager.java:335)
>       at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.createAccessor(MappingManager.java:297)
>       at org.test.impl.persist.CassandraRepository.lambda$getAll$5(CassandraRepository.java:99)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:981)
>       ... 61 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>       at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AccessorMapper.prepare(AccessorMapper.java:57)
>       ... 65 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onTimeout(RequestHandler.java:825)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ResponseHandler$1.run(Connection.java:1392)
>       at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:668)
>       at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:743)
>       at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:471)
>       ... 2 common frames omitted

Accessor

```
@Accessor
public interface TestAccessor {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM test_table")
    Result<TestTable> getAll();
}
```

Usage

```
TestAccessor acc = mappingManager.createAccessor(TestAccessor.class);
Result<TestTable> channels = acc.getAll();
```

Provide session and mapper.

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule implements ServiceGuiceSupport, AkkaGuiceSupport {
    private static CompletableFuture<Void> codecRegistrationPromise = new CompletableFuture<>();

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindService(TestService.class, TestServiceImpl.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public CompletionStage<MappingManager> provideMappingManager(CompletionStage<Session> session) {
        return session.thenApply(MappingManager::new));
    }

    @Provides
    public CompletionStage<Cluster> provideCassandraCluster(CompletionStage<Session> session) {
        return session.thenApply(Session::getCluster);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public CompletionStage<Session> provideCassandraSession(CassandraSession sessionWrapper) {
        CompletableFuture<Session> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        completeWithSession(sessionWrapper, future);
        return future;
    }

    private void completeWithSession(CassandraSession sessionWrapper, CompletableFuture<Session> future) {
        sessionWrapper.underlying().whenComplete((session, throwable) -> {
            if (throwable != null) {
                if (throwable instanceof NoServiceLocatorException) {
                    log.error("Failed to obtain Cassandra session, try again", throwable);
                    completeWithSession(sessionWrapper, future);
                } else {
                    log.error("Failed to obtain Cassandra session", throwable);
                    future.completeExceptionally(throwable);
                }
            } else {
                log.info("Cassandra session obtained");
                future.complete(session);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Usage in some class

```
@Inject
    public CassandraRepository(CompletionStage<MappingManager> mappingManagerPromise, ActorSystem system) {
        this.mappingManagerPromise = mappingManagerPromise;
        this.system = system;
    }



    mappingManagerPromise.thenApply(mappingManager -> {
                    TestAccessor acc = mappingManager.createAccessor(TestAccessor.class);
Result<TestTable> channels = acc.getAll();
                })
```

If I'm using mapper.getAsync all fine.

```
Mapper<TestTable> mapper = mappingManager.mapper(TestTable.class);
            return toCompletableFuture(mapper.getAsync(id));
```

Comment: How do you specify keyspace? Show the code that creates the `mappingManager`

Comment: @AlexOtt I added this to the main part

Keyspace is defined in the **application.conf**
cassandra.keyspace = test_keyspace

Comment: can you try with `SELECT * FROM test_keyspace.test_table` ?

Comment: @AlexOtt Yeah, I thought about this too. But when I did it with this query I got an error again :(
If you mean `@Query()`

Comment: Ah, it's timing out... See "Timed out waiting for server response at " - check connection to Cassandra.

Comment: @AlexOtt I saw this error. But I have two routes, 1st with mapper.getAsync and 2nd with Accessor. At the same time, the first works, and the second throws a connection error. It's strange..